# Calculating $\int_0^\infty Mn x^{n-1} \cdot \exp(-Mx^n-Ax^b)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve $$\int_0^\infty Mn x^{n-1} \cdot \exp(-Mx^n-Ax^b)dx=C$$ wrt $A$ and $b$.
Here $M>0$, $n>0$ and $0<C<1$ are known constants and $A>0$ and $b>0$ are unknown.

I was not able to calculate this integral using WolframAlpha.

I thought about using numerical methods, but I am not sure how to use them considering I have these unknown constants in the expression.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: I started by using the substitution $u=\exp(-Mx^n)$, which seems like a good starting point but then I hit a wall. That pesky $Ax^b$ term ruins it! Perhaps someone smarter can pick up from here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, it just does not fit in comments. Numerically, it seems that you get an infinite number of solutions. In the picture below, you can see (for $M=1, n=2, C=0.5$) the $(A,b)$ solutions as the zero contour in the center.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about this condition?